# PDF417 image generation API recommendation

Tags: java, grails, barcode

in a grails application I need to generate a PDF417 image and send it via email. Can anybody recommend me a (hopefully free) grails plugin or java library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The barcode4j plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/barcode4j) uses barcode4j which has support for PDF417 among others.

Here's a sample controller action that would generate an image and render it to the browser:

```
import org.krysalis.barcode4j.impl.pdf417.PDF417Bean

class TestController {
   def index = {

      def generator = new PDF417Bean()
      generator.height = 10

      def barcodeValue = "12345"
      renderBarcodePng(generator, barcodeValue)
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Why is there a DEMO string in the generated image ? Is there a way ti get rid of it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the "send it via email" part of your feature, I recommend the [mail plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/mail). The documentation explains how to configure and use it.